# IIS rewrite rule to remove slash

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

We had some emails sent out by someone where they messed up the url to be /pagename.aspx/?email=emailaddress

instead of /pagename.aspx?email=emailaddress

I need a rewrite rule to remove that slash after .aspx, does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried something? You can create the rule in IIS manager.

Comment: That was the question, what the rewrite rule format would be.  We ended up just using absolute URLs as the page was working but not the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert this rule in your web.config:

```
<rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)/$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Just for more understandig see https://nicolas.guelpa.me/blog/2015/02/21/rewrite-redirect-iis.html